# Intuitive understanding of bindings in Angular

Tags: html, angular, binding, angular2-template, angular5

I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding of how to determine the differences between square brackets binding `<elem [...]="..."><elem>` and parentheses binding `<elem (...)="..."<elem>`. Any rule of thumb that will help to distinguish between the two. Some thing like a "Banana in the box" for two-way binding syntax reminder.

Comment: Binding in the box [], fire in the hole () ? //Fire for event

Comment: [...] is called Property binding, (..) is called event Binding. A property can be "disabled", "innerHtml",... A event Binding can be "click" "change".. Always will be a function in your .ts. Property binding can be the result of a function or an expresion or a variable

Answer (score 0):

As written here : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

and as @Eliseo reported, there is a difference between properties interpolation, firing events and both of them.

[image]